# SSH and HTTP connections refused from ec2 instance, but the instance is in running state

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2

My ec2 instance (CentOS 6.3) has been in running state all time but I was unable to make SSH and HTTP request to the instance until making AMI from the instance and launching new instance.

Another weird thing is that the server logs didn't kept any data for 28-09-2014, actually my instance was unavailable for one day without any state changes in the AWS Console.

I only can see that a lot of memory was used on 27-09-2014 (this is the last memory record on 27th, I don't have log file for 28th Sep):

```
# sar -r -f /var/log/sa/sa27

07:00:01    kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit
07:10:01        28984   1707192     98.33    126252    344868   1502068
07:20:01        27496   1708680     98.42    126396    344968   1503092
07:30:01        26008   1710168     98.50    126512    345096   1504628
07:40:01        26752   1709424     98.46    126612    345184   1503604
07:50:01        25380   1710796     98.54    126772    345248   1504628
08:00:01        26000   1710176     98.50    126896    345288   1503604
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check CloudWatch monitoring to see what the CPU as doing.

If the CPU was max'ed out, you would not have been able to make a HTTP or SSH connection.

If you're running something like Wordpress on an EC2 instance, prolonged CPU spikes are common.

Comment: I am running Magento... prolonged CPU spikes might be an issue.